# How do I find the sum of all subscriptions from a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to get the input from 3 customers and what they want to subscribe to. Then I need to find the individual cost as well as the cost for all subscribers.

I have found how to get the total cost for each individual customer, but I can't figure out how to get the sum of all subscribers. This is my code so far.

```
#prompt for input
for i in range(3):
  months_subscribed = float(input("How many months would you like to subscribe? "))
  ad_free_months = float(input("How many months would you like ad free? "))
  video_on_demand_purchases = float(input("How many video on demand purchases? "))
  print ()

#cost for each customer 
  if months_subscribed % 3 == 0:
    as_string = str(months_subscribed * 6.00 + ad_free_months * 2.00 + video_on_demand_purchases * 27.99)
  else:
    as_string = str(months_subscribed * 7.00 + ad_free_months * 2.00 + video_on_demand_purchases * 27.99)
  print("--> Your total subscription cost is: " + as_string)
  print()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added some code to your script to sum the total of all customers. Try it out I think this is what you demand. :)

```
#prompt for input
totalsOfCustomers = []
for i in range(3):
  months_subscribed = float(input("How many months would you like to subscribe? "))
  ad_free_months = float(input("How many months would you like ad free? "))
  video_on_demand_purchases = float(input("How many video on demand purchases? "))
  print ()

#cost for each customer
  if months_subscribed % 3 == 0:
    res = months_subscribed * 6.00 + ad_free_months * 2.00 + video_on_demand_purchases * 27.99
    as_string = str(res)
  else:
    res = months_subscribed * 7.00 + ad_free_months * 2.00 + video_on_demand_purchases * 27.99
    as_string = str(res)
  totalsOfCustomers.append(res)
  print("--> Your total subscription cost is: " + as_string)
  print()

totalSum = 0
for total in totalsOfCustomers:
  totalSum += total
print("Total of all customers = " + str(totalSum))
```

Comment: This did work, thank you so much. I'm pretty new to programing so I still know all the terms. What is 'res'?

Comment: its simply result in this context

Answer (score 0):

Add your sums to a total sum (stored in a new variable).

```py
total = 0
for i in range(3):
  months_subscribed = float(input("How many months would you like to subscribe? "))
  ad_free_months = float(input("How many months would you like ad free? "))
  video_on_demand_purchases = float(input("How many video on demand purchases? "))
  print ()

  #cost for each customer 
  if months_subscribed % 3 == 0:
    customer_total = months_subscribed * 6.00 + ad_free_months * 2.00 + video_on_demand_purchases * 27.99
  else:
    customer_total = months_subscribed * 7.00 + ad_free_months * 2.00 + video_on_demand_purchases * 27.99
  total += customer_total
  print("--> Your total subscription cost is:", customer_total)
  print()


print("Total sum:", total)
```

As you can see, you don't need the string-cast, because `print` accept (multiple) non-string arguments as well.